# Use $(a,b)=1$ and $a | bc$ then $a | c$ to show that if $p$ is prime and $a$ is an integer with $p | a^2$, then $p | a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

problem : Use $(a,b)=1$ and $a | bc$  then $a | c$ to show that if $p$ is prime and $a$ is an integer with $p | a^2$, then $p | a$

What I've done: 
Use contradiction that assume $p$ does not divide $a$, then $(p, a) = 1$

and I am stuck here....

what is the next step or how can i prove this question?

Comment: Then $(p,a) = 1$, but $p \mid a^2 = a \times a$ , so $p | a$ (in the lemma, take $b=c=a$),contradiction.

Comment: Let $p=A^*$ and $a=B^*=C^*. $ Then $A^*|B^*C^*$ and $A^*$ is prime so if $A^*\not |\; B^*$ then .....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what it says:

Prove the following lemma:

Lemma:  If $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $a|bc$ then $a|c$.

Proof: .... that's for you to do....

Then use that to prove if $p$ is prime and $p|a^2$ then $p|a$>

Either $\gcd(a,p) = 1$ or $\gcd(a,p) = p$.  If $p|a^2=a*a$ and $\gcd(a,p) = 1$ then $p|a$ which contradicts $\gcd(a,p) = 1$.  So $\gcd(a,p) = p$ and $p|a$.

That's it.

Okay... proof of the lemma....  If $a|bc$ then $\frac {bc}a$ is an integer.  So  all the factors of $a$ divide into $bc$.  Bt $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ so $a$ and $b$ have no factors in common.  So none of the factors of $a$ divide into $bc$.  So all the factors of $a$ divide into $c$.  So $a$ divides $c$.